# Loading container service on Controller constructor, Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to load container service at Controller constructor, like

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

    protected $breadcrumb;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //initializing breadcrumb
        $breadcrumbs = $this->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem("Dashboard", "adminPage");
        $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem("Post", "postPage");
        $this->breadcrumb = $breadcrumbs;
    }
//..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via [Controller as a Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html). However, injecting the Container is considered a bad example. If you want to get the service `white_october_breadcrumbs`, you can just inject this in your controller service definition; If you use yaml:

```
service:
    class: app.controller.my_controller
    arguments:
        - "@white_october_breadcrumbs"
```

```php
public function __construct(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs)
{
    $this->breadcrumbs = $breadcrumbs;
}
```

This is a far nicer solution because you don't want your application to depend on the container whenever possible.

Another solution, considering you want this on multiple pages, would be to use event listeners or even custom annotations on actions to add breadcrumbs dynamically. This is not recommended for beginners though.

Comment: Defining every controller class as a service will not be meaningful for me and I want to add breadcrumb for multiple pages so can you give detail on second approach or another simple way.

Comment: I recommend to put every controller as a service as it will help you on the long run. You can play around with the kernel.request and kernel.controller events if you want to fire things at specific moments.

Answer (score 5):

You are extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` class which gets `container` injected by setter injection (method `setContainer`) and not by constructor argument.

While you are in your `__construct()` you don't have your `$container` available yet. So solution for you is to override `setContainer` method (which is called by service container, right after controller is constructed) and put your logic there (instead of `__construct()`).

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

    protected $breadcrumb;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer($container);
        $breadcrumbs = $container->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem("Dashboard", "adminPage");
        $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem("Post", "postPage");
        $this->breadcrumb = $breadcrumbs;
    }

}
```

Other solution, requiring a little bit more work, is to [define your controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and set it up so it gets `container` as a constructor argument

Comment: This will solve the issue but I assume it's not the best approach and same question, doing same thing for every controller class will be troublesome job, are there any other approach, so that I can code as normal.

Comment: you can either add event listener http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html or extract ``BaseController`` class, put your overriden ``setContainer`` method and then each of your controller should extend your ``BaseController``

Answer (score 0):

> Loading container service on Controller constructor, Symfony

Don't. What is the lifecycle of your service? You want to initialize some breadcrumbs if an action of your controller is invoked? What about subrequests? In which order are the controllers created?

**1. Either central configuration:**

1. create a config map (e.g. in yml) with controller classname as key and the breadcrumbs as value (e.g. routes array)
2. create a `BreadcrumbBuilder` service, inject the config
3. create a `BreadcrumbProvider` standalone service and twig-extension for your views
4. create and register a `BreadcrumbRequestListener` http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html listener, inject `BreadcrumbBuilder`, `BreadcrumbProvider
5. create your breadcrumbs depending of the `getController()`-callable (sample A)
6. access the breadcrumbs directly in twig

Sample A:

```
$controller = $event->getController();
if(\is_array($controller)) {
  $clazz = \get_class($controller[0]);
  $breadcrumbs = $this->breadcrumbBuilder->build($clazz);
  $this->breadcrumbProvider->setBreadcrumbs($breadcrumbs);
}
```

**2. Or Open-Closed controllers, so you don't need to change a central config, but just add controllers:**

1. let every controller which provides a breadcrumb be a `BreadcrumbProviderInterface` implementing `getBreadcrumb()` returning some data you need to create the breadcrumbs
2. also create a `BreadcrumbRequestListener`, check for that interface and store the reference which is accessible via twig (Sample B)

Sample B:

```
$controller = $event->getController();
if(\is_array($controller) && $controller[0] instanceof BreadcrumbProviderInterface) {
  $this->breadcrumbs->setCurrentProvider($controller[0]);
}
```

**3. Other ideas:**

- requesting the breadcrumbs via walking through the `request_stack` having the controller and action on `$request->attributes->get('_controller');`. You can just use the main request or iterate through all breadcrumbs from all controllers
- base controller class

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. Here my scenario: 
I have a third party bundle class, declared as service in `vendor/my-vendor/my-third-party-bundle/Resources/config/services.xml`, which I wanted to inject in my `src/AppBundle/Controller/MyController`. Namespaces are set correctly and everything works fine when I get my third party bundle class from the container in some action method of the controller above. For examle:

`class MyController extends Controller 
{
    public function myAction()
    {
// ...
        $myThirdPartyBundleService = $this->container
            ->get('my_third_party_bundle_service.class');
// ...
    }
}`

What I've tried is to declare the controller as service, following the official (Symfony docs)[http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html], since I am using the service several times in the controller.
It seem's that in `MyThirdPartyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyThirdPartyBundleExtension::load()` I have the service build. I also tried to put `die('my-third-party-bundle');` in the load() method and in `MyAppBundle\Controller\MyControlle::__construct()` I tried `die('controller')` just to see which one is loaded first. As I expected the result which was first returned is the one from the third party bundle. I also tried a `die('my_app_bundle');` in `MyAppBundle\DependencyInjection\MyAppBundleExtension::load();`. As I tried, the result depends from the order in which the bundles are declared in the AppKernel. So I've changed MyThirdPartyBundle to load before MyAppBundle. And I still don not have the desired result and get instead `NULL`. It seems that at this point my third party bundle's class is not build yet. I do not have much time to inspect why this is happen, but I suspect that the reason is the container's configuration build. So the most simple and fast thing that I can do is to override the Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::setContainer()``` in the MyAppBundle's controller. It is not the most elegant way to solve the problem, but it works. I think that the correct way is to declare controller as service, but it seems that it is not working in my case.